# How do I correctly test a web scraping library

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, web-scraping, jestjs

I'm currently writing a library in typescript that retrieves videos from certain pages. I'm using jest to write the test but I'm facing the problem of testing the scraper since some content is dynamic and the library makes some post requests to store some cookies mocks are not feasible, what would be the correct way to test such a library?

Comment: why are *mocks not feasible*?

Comment: @Lux content is dynamic and I store session/cookies so I can't mock content that I don't know, also if the library isn't able to scrape the site it's not working so the test wouldn't work with mocks